# How to get text at runtime from XAML file included in project?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013

I have several **UserControls** defined in **XAML** files with **Page** build action in VS 2013 and (idealy) i want to read XAML text at runtime and display it in WPF application TextEdit. I know i should use **XamlReader** but i can't reach the content itself :)

So the questions are:

1. Is there any way to reach XAML file embedded in app using **Page** build action to read its XML content? Likely it is converted to BAML in the process so it's not possible to do but may be i don't know smth.
2. I've tried to set **Copy always** option for XAML file in the project (to read XAML text from an external file at least) but only the code behind **.cs** file is copied. Is there any way to easily copy XAML file on project build?
3. Any other way to read and display XAML content in WPF application i'm unaware of?

PS: If there are any free libs with similar capabilities exist then +1 if you'll mention them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Sure.  When the build action is Page, the xaml gets compiled.  So, to get the xaml from it, simply instantiate a copy and throw it through the XAML serializer.  Now you've got the xaml representation of the object graph.  Probably not what you need or think you want, but it works 100%.
2. Change the build action.  Or add a Resource to your project and point it at the xaml file.
3. Probably.  Depends on your *goal*.  You could always disassemble something like kaxaml to see how a simple xaml editor that actually loads and displays xaml code at runtime. Without telling us your *goal*, we can't give you advice on how to *accomplish it*.  Also, asking for links is off topic.

Comment: I want to show  XAML source for some controls so it must be exactly the same as used to show the controls itself in WPF. Maybe even allow user to edit it and load into app in runtime. As i can see the easiest way is to work with files, but as i can't simply copy XAML on build it brings me some headache as i have numerous controls and i don't want to add each control XAML definition somewhere manualy.

Comment: 1.Is deserialized XAML will be identical to the one used to initialy render the control?   2. I think i can't change build action as i use these files to render controls in WPF app.

Comment: @AlexanderSmirnov Your goal is weird, which makes me think there is some other goal behind your decision. If you want users to be able to rewrite your xaml controls at runtime (????? who is qualified to do this? Are you targeting WPF developers for your application?), then you need to add the xaml files as string resources. Edit the text of the control at runtime, and deserialize the xaml into an object you add to your visual tree.  Does it *seem* like you're going down a rabbit hole? Because you're going down a rabbit hole.

Comment: You're right at guessing. It's kinda of showcase app where user can change XAML and reapply (replace) it to rendered control. Thanks for tip with resource files, i think i'll stick with it for now though i'll have to add two XAML files for each control.